# Serialized JSON string doesn´t deserialize as expected (DateTime)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a JSON string serialized as this: (in VSTO automatio APP)

```
string miPublicacionStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(miPublicacion).ToString();

{"IdPublicacion":0.0,"FechaPublicacion":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","IdUsuario":"juanp","FechaPublicacionHasta":"2013-02-17T00:00:00-05:00","FechaArchivoHasta":"2013-02-17T00:00:00-05:00","Suscriptores_IdSuscriptor":1,"IdTipoPublicacion":1.0}
```

Then I send this to a web site and it arrives to my action controller as this

```
{"IdPublicacion":0.0,"FechaPublicacion":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","IdUsuario":"juanp","FechaPublicacionHasta":"2013-02-17T00:00:00-05:00","FechaArchivoHasta":"2013-02-17T00:00:00-05:00","Suscriptores_IdSuscriptor":1,"IdTipoPublicacion":1.0}
```

There is no diferences between them. But when try to deserialize on my web site using:

```
Publicacion miPublicacion = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Publicacion>(miPublicacionJsonString);
```

It throws a `FormatException` with message "The string has wrong format"

This is the object that must map:

```
public partial class Publicacion
{
    public decimal IdPublicacion { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime FechaPublicacion { get; set; }
    public string IdUsuario { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime FechaPublicacionHasta { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime FechaArchivoHasta { get; set; }
    public int Suscriptores_IdSuscriptor { get; set; }
    public decimal IdTipoPublicacion { get; set; }
}
```

What can i do to avoid this problem?

Comment: Does removing the timezone part help? Can't you just stay away from TZ madness and just use GMT as milliseconds instead of a serialized date?

Comment: What mean .... removing timezone part ? , JSon string was generated automatically .

Comment: My guess is that the last part of `"2013-02-17T00:00:00-05:00"` (i.e. the `"-05:00"` part) is the time zone. May be it's correctly serialized but not deserialized. I'd just stay away from that unless needed. Also using datetime apparently is not sending a very accurate time but just full seconds, isn't that going to be a problem? Using the number of milliseconds as a double instead seems to me both simpler and better.

Comment: Ahhh, ok tks for your help. Is the first time I work with it. But finally, looking into my objects definition ,found tahat some property was cahnged from decimal to int, and when deserialize a decimal to int it was causing the problem .very tks for your time.